# Unable to create a pipeline in ms-azure-devops

Tags: azure-pipelines

I would like to create a pipeline for the repository Networking-scripts-lib. When I tried to create a pipleine am facing the below issue.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TW96g.png)

Answer (score 0):

Each pipeline in Azure Devops requires you to either have permissions to edit that pipeline individually, or a broader scope of permissions in the project (or organization). It seems you don't have one, so you need to find somebody who has permissions at the pipeline, project, or organization, to give you appropriate permissions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/policies/permissions?view=azure-devops

I think you can find who has permissions to do so following something like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/policies/set-permissions?view=azure-devops#confirm-that-contributors-have-pipeline-permissions. Usually a few people are in the "build administrator" or "Project administrator" groups, some times, specific users are added manually and should be visible there, otherwise you need to find out who is on each group (this could be helpful in that case https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/add-team-administrator?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page)